# How could I translate Caesar cipher code back to normal in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, caesar-cipher, string-conversion

I'm wondering how I can translate a Caesar cipher code into a normal text. I have already done translating normal text into Cipher code, and this is how I did it:

```
def conversion(chr,ord):
    for letter in stringinput:
            cipheresult = chr(ord(letter) + int(shiftnumber))
            print(cipheresult)
```

So I'm wondering how I could do the complete opposite of this and translate it back to what would have been the stringinput. The shiftnumber variable is determined by what the user is inputting into the program, by the way.

Thanks

Comment: Your Caesar cipher logic is wrong. it should be `cipher = chr((ord(letter) + int(shift)) % ord('a|A'))`

Comment: To decipher `decipher = chr((ord(cipher) - int(shift) + 26) % ord('a|A'))` use either lowercase or uppercase letter in caesar cipher.

Comment: Why do you pass ord and chr as arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your function should not take `chr` and `ord` as arguments. Instead, input your string and the amount by which you want to shift. A common way to implement a ciper is to use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, ascii_letters

def cipher(text, shift):
    translation = str.maketrans(
        ascii_letters,
        ascii_lowercase[shift:] + ascii_lowercase[:shift] +\
        ascii_uppercase[shift:] + ascii_uppercase[:shift]
    )

    return text.translate(translation)

secret_msg = cipher('Python is cool!', 1) # 'Qzuipo jt dppm!'
```

Finally, since ciphering shifts characters by `k`, the inverse operation is simply to cipher by `-k`.

```
msg = cipher('Qzuipo jt dppm!', -1) # Python is cool!
```